# Icons not displaying

Tags: html, css

I am building a simple webpage. The text is displaying correctly but the icon is not displaying. The icon is from ionicons framework.

I checked ionicons.min.css path and icon name in this css file

My html file:

```
<!--DOCHtml5-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>webpage</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Euphoria+Script" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montez" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="icons/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "name">
        Name
        <ul class = "social-icons">
            <li><i class="ion-arrow-right-a"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

My css file:

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: 'Euphoria Script', cursive;
    font-size: 100px;    
}

body{
    height:100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #ef6758;
}

.name{
    position:absolute;
    top:35%;
    left:31%;
    font-family: 'Montez', cursive;
    color: #4be214;
}

.social-icons li{
    list-style: none;
}
```

Icon should be visible

Comment: problem definitely in path ionicons.min.css right click in browser and check error if path not found ionicons.min.css

Comment: Try http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css cdn

Comment: keep the icons in the correct path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through it. it will work for you, because there is font-family files not found in your css

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: 'Euphoria Script', cursive;
    font-size: 100px;    
}

body{
    height:100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #ef6758;
}

.name{
    position:absolute;
    top:35%;
    left:31%;
    font-family: 'Montez', cursive;
    color: #4be214;
}

.social-icons li{
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!--DOCHtml5-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>webpage</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Euphoria+Script" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montez" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "name">
        Name
        <ul class = "social-icons">
            <li><i class="ion-arrow-right-a"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code fixed my issue.The icon is visible now.But I hosted this code using github,in that link again icon is missing

Comment: https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css   add this stylesheet link, it will work

Comment: should i add this link in css file?Like added in html file?

Comment: add it in head section of html

Comment: This link is added in html file,still issue occurs.

Comment: there is no any link that i provide, copy above answer code and check